# Create a object of nested functions using an array of strings to form the object keys

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, method-chaining

I am using the following construct as a Mock object which functions as an object with chainable methods:

```
PlayerNull =
  find : ->
    populate : ->
      exec : (callback) ->
        callback false, false
```

In my tests I then substitute the real model for this Mock object and my controller calls each of the functions in turn such as:

```
Model.find().populate().exec(callback)
```

As I'm finding myself using this many times, I was curious as to whether I could create a helper function to simplify this (slightly), using a helper function in the following form:

```
PlayerNull = helper.mockNest ['find', 'populate', 'exec'], (callback) ->
  callback false, false
```

I've come to the following function code, however this is not working:

```
exports.mockNest = (func_names, func_final) ->
  func_names.reverse()
  func_next = func_final
  for func_name in func_names
    _func_next = func_next.bind({})
    _next = {}
    _next[func_name] = ->
      _func_next
    func_next = _func_next
  func_next
```

I've come to the realization that I need to clone `func_next` each loop or else the reference seems to be maintained and assigning to `func_next` just seems to alter all previous assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've identified the problem correctly that the reference is not maintained, it's the classical [closure in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572) problem.

However, cloning the function doesn't really help here, your actual problem is

> ```
> _next[func_name] = ->
>   _func_next
> ```

which creates a closure over the `_func_next` variable, which is modified in each loop iteration.

It should rather be

```
exports.mockNest = (func_names, func_final) ->
  func_names.reverse()
  func_next = func_final
  for func_name in func_names
    next = {}
    next[func_name] = func_next
    func_next = do (_next = next) ->
      () ->
        _next
  func_next
```

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining the problem and bringing my attention to the `do` keyword, very cool, and got me over the finish line. Your final code didn't work exactly, I'll add an answer and accept this.

Comment: Oops, you're right it didn't work; but the fix is rather small. In contrast to your code, it even works with an empty `func_names` array now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bergi's explanation, I came to the following solution:

```
exports.mockNest = (func_names, func_final) ->

  # Assign the last function to the provided func_final
  func_name_final = func_names.pop()
  func_next = {}
  func_next[func_name_final] = func_final

  # Reverse the array so we build the object from last to first.
  func_names.reverse()
  for func_name in func_names
    ignore = do (func_name, _func_next = func_next) ->
      func_next = {}
      func_next[func_name] = ->
        _func_next
      return
  func_next
```

To explain the changes, I needed to preserve the supplied func_final, so I had to assign before the loop.

Also, I needed to assign the `do` block to variable `ignore` or else Coffeescript compiled the function to different location where changes made to `func_next` were made out-of-order. Assigning ensures the placement of the `do` block.